# Generalization of Campbell's theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-process

Consider a point process $\Phi=(X_i)$ defined on $[0,1]$.

Is there any formula for computing
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sum_{X_i\in \Phi}X_i^d}{(\sum_{X_i\in \Phi}X_i)^d}\right]?
$$

[Campbell’s theorem (formula)](https://hpaulkeeler.com/campbells-theorem-formula/) seems to be related but not actually what I want. Any references/suggestions?